# How can I run schedule job with out windows service on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, hangfire, quartz

I have sent a mail that works locally using asp.net and quartz. It works very well. but it didn't work when I put it on the server. They said that because it is shared hosting, they cannot run it for security reasons. Sql Agent is also not provided as standard.
I guess HangFire doesn't use windows service. I could not find how to do it with asp.net web form either.

Comment: Change the hosting :P Other than that I see no reason for the scheduler not work to send an email. Quartz.net are simply threads inside your asp.net application process.

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't Quartz but sending the email? As @Isma says it should work.

Comment: I have 20 website in hosting not change now :).  send mail works fine on my local network with quartz.net. The backdate field in SQL table if backdate expire than send mail perfectly. but publish to server doest not work.

Comment: Oh my god.. :) change quartz version 2.2.4 to 2.5 running perfectly.. :) thanks @Isma

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone needs this code for Asp.net webform.

**EmailJob Code**

```
public class EmailJob : IJob
{

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        sendmail();
    }

   public void sendMail()
    {
       //send mail code
    }

}
```

**JobScheduler code** working 00.00 for every day. you can change what you want.. :)

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().Build();


        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(00, 00))
                .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Local)
              )
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

**Global.asax** start jobscheduler

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JobScheduler.Start();

    }
```